# Direct products $\mathbb Z_m \times \mathbb Z_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $A = \mathbb{Z}_{18}, B = \mathbb{Z}_9 \times \mathbb{Z}_2, C = \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_6$ decide which of the pairs $AB, AC, BC$ are isomorphic and which are not. Explain why, if isomorphic, and if not exhibit an explicit algebraic property true for one member of the pair and not the other.

Comment: What are your thoughts? Did you try anything?

Answer (score 1):

Two hints:

1. If two cyclic groups have the same order, they are isomorphic. (Why?)
2. Isomorphisms preserve the orders of elements.  Hence, if there is an element of order $n$ in one group, then any group isomorphic to it will also have an element of order $n$.

*Only after* you have given the problem some thought, these articles might be helpful:

http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Group_Direct_Product_of_Cyclic_Groups

http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Cyclic_Groups_of_Same_Order_are_Isomorphic

Answer (score 0):

Note that each of $A$ and $B$ has an element of order $18$. In $A$, you can take this element to be $1$, and in $B$, you can take it to be $(1,1)$. Since each group is also of order $18$, these groups are cyclic of the same order and hence isomorphic.

However, $C$ is not cyclic. It has order $18$, but the maximal order of any element in $C$ is $6$. Therefore, $C$ is not isomorphic to either $A$ or $B$.